# Can't update tortoisehg in Ubuntu KDE

Tags: apt, software-installation, kde, mercurial

I'm trying to update tortoisehg as the current version that I have is 2.2, however:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tortoisehg
tortoisehg is already the newest version
```

I have also tried these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tortoisehg
```

But I'm getting `add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: Related: [How to install 'add-apt-repository' using the terminal?](//askubuntu.com/q/493460)

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

[Found in this article: Missing add-apt-repository command](http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/)